# save image captured by camera in external storage in android

Tags: android, camera, external, sensors

I am using camera in my app, by calling the camera api in my app itself, (I am not doing intent to open the main camera application of android).

I am showing an overlay image on the screen while camera preview is on, that overlay image is animated as per the change in orientation sensor.

My problem is that when ever i capture the image, the image is captured and is shown on the screen, but it is not saved in the external directory, i have tried my best, but i didn't succedded, plz. help me that how I can save the image into the external directory, your help should be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance. I am posting my whole code, plz help me what and where to implement .....

```
package com.example.compassapp;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.util.Random;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.hardware.Camera;
 import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
 import android.hardware.Sensor;
 import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
 import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
 import android.hardware.SensorManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.view.animation.Animation;
 import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
 import android.widget.FrameLayout;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

// define the display assembly compass picture
private ImageView image;


// record the compass picture angle turned
private float currentDegree = 0f;

// device sensor manager
private SensorManager mSensorManager;

TextView tvHeading;
Canvas canvas;
FrameLayout preview;
ImageButton button_capture;
private Camera cameraObject;
   private ShowCamera showCamera;
   private ImageView pic;
   public static Camera isCameraAvailiable(){
      Camera object = null;
      try {
         object = Camera.open(); 
      }
      catch (Exception e){
      }
      return object; 
   }

   private PictureCallback capturedIt = new PictureCallback() {

      @Override
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
      if(bitmap==null){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      else
      {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
      }
      cameraObject.release();
   }
      private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap){
          String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
            myDir.mkdirs();
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
            File file = new File (myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
            try {
                   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                   out.flush();
                   out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    button_capture=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_capture);        


    cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable();
    //showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
    showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
     preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
     preview.addView(showCamera);

     button_capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                cameraObject.takePicture(null, null, capturedIt);
            //cameraObject.takePicture(null, null, capturedIt);


        }
    });        




    // our compass image


    // TextView that will tell the user what degree is he heading
    tvHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);

    // initialize your android device sensor capabilities
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // for the system's orientation sensor registered listeners
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // to stop the listener and save battery
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    // get the angle around the z-axis rotated
    float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);

    tvHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(degree) + " degrees");

    // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)

    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree, 
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    // how long the animation will take place
    ra.setDuration(210);

    // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
    ra.setFillAfter(true);

    // Start the animation
    image.startAnimation(ra);
    currentDegree = -degree;


}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // not in use
}


public void onBackPressed() {

    //super.onBackPressed();
    Log.d("back button", "back button pressed");
    AlertDialog.Builder ad1=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ad1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit? ");
    ad1.setCancelable(false);


    ad1.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {             
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {   


        }
    });

    ad1.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {   

            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert=ad1.create();
    alert.show();   

            }
  }
```

Comment: I have found the way to store the image in the sd card, but now the problem is that i want to call that image in the another activity, so any help, that what to implement in the above code, to call that image in the image view of another activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
add this code in onActivityResult. This will store your image in a folder named "FolderName"

String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
        + File.separator + "YourFolderName";
File myPath = new File(extr, FolderName);
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
    bitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),
            bitMap, myPath.getPath(), uniqueFileName);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

also need to set permission on Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

[Refere this](http://androidexample.com/Camera_Video_Capture_And_Save_On_SDCard_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=123&aaid=143)

Comment: hey thats not working, how can I add the onActivityResult in the code, I am not using any type of intents,, if possible can you give me the part of the code on adding this into my code. thank you

Comment: @MirnalMannu see i put one reference link also so it might be helpful to you also

Comment: As i hvae told you earlier, that I am not using any type of intent to call the inbuilt android camera app, I am using camera API in my app which calls the camera inside the app,it does not opens the main camera app of android.it just uses the camera api.

Comment: @MirnalMannu then put this code inside SaveImage( Bitmap urBitmap) function then you can able to solve error

Answer (score 0):

Have you put this permision in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: yes i have given this permission in the manifest file, yet it is not working and is not saving the image in the file, plz help how to resolve this problem , with proper changing in my code if possible, thank you.

Comment: try using "/sdcard" instead of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()

Comment: still thats not working.. Can you help me by giving any option so that i can make a button which just take the screenshot, while the camera is on, and save the image, indirectly the image will be saved, any option like that..

Comment: thats not a good idea dont do that, and in your code you don't call the function SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) anywhere

Comment: but except that, I have tried all the way, but i am unsuccessfull,,, also I have tried implementing the screenshot phenomena, but it is not doing my work, as it only captures the overlay image on the camera, it does not capture the camera preview which is shown on the screen , only the overlay image with black background is captured, any way to capture the whole thing, including the camera preview.